# Worst case Analysis On a loop

Tags: java, time, complexity-theory, analysis

So I wrote this loop but I'm having trouble analyzing its worst case time complexity. Any help would greatly be appreciated .

factor is any arbitrary number 
primeNumber is a list of prime numbers between 2 and the original value of factor

```
for (int i = 0; i < primeNumbers.size() - 1; i++) {
    prime = primeNumbers.get(i);
    if(prime<=factor) {
        if (factor % prime == 0) {
            factor = factor / prime;
            divisors.add(prime);
            i = 0;
        }
        if (factor <= 3) 
            break;
    }
    else 
        break;
}
```

Comment: What is `factor` and where is it defined?

Comment: Well, assuming that `primeNumbers` has an arbitrary size of `n`, how many times *at most* could it run?

Comment: yah just revised it and added more info and yah i'm trying to see how many times at most could it run

Comment: It runs at most (primeNumbers.size() - 1) times. which means it is O(n).

Comment: Seriously... your worst scenario would be that every element in `primeNumbers` is less than `factor`, so it is O(N). Also, since you won't change the state of `primeNumbers`, it would be better using enhanced `for` loop because some lists may traverse the whole list in `List#get`, or use an `Iterator`.

Comment: Possibly relevant: The number of primes less than `x` is roughly `x / ln x`: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime-counting_function

Answer (score 2):

Worst scenario:
factor is prime.
So we never get to `break` instruction.
And cycle body would be executed `primeNumbers.size()` times.

Now we should evaluate `primeNumbers.size()`.
It's [number of prime numbers below a given number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number#Number_of_prime_numbers_below_a_given_number) = `O(n/ln n)`.

Lets prove that getting to `if (factor % prime == 0)` statement will decrease number of calculations.
If we get there that would mean that `factor = p*m`.
So we'll get `O(p/ln(p) + m/ln(m))` = `O((p*ln(m) + m/ln(p))/(ln(m)*ln(p)))` < `O((p*m)/(ln(m)*ln(p)))` < `O((p*m)/(ln(m) + ln(p)))` = `O(p*m/ln(m*p))` = `O(n/ln n)`.
So dividing this way we decreasing number of calculations.

Comment: Did you take into consideration that if factor%prime==0 we reset the counter to 0 and restart, although with a different factor

Comment: Good point. It was just intuition that dividing will only decrease amount of calculations. I added formal prove for this case.

Comment: ooh wow you're really good at this.. haha well it makes sense to me now thanks alot Nikolay

Answer (score 0):

Nikolay's response gives the most direct response to the question you asked, which was specifically about the performance complexity in terms of the number of division operations, assuming that every division operation has a uniform cost.  Two observations however:

1) You can dramatically improve the performance of this test by stopping the loop whenever prime^2 > factor.  The reason for this is that if you do not find a divisor below the square root of the factor, you will not find one above the square root, either.  With this modification, you will get an updated performance of O(sqrt(n)/ln(sqrt(n))) = O(sqrt(n)/(sqrt(n)/2)) = O(sqrt(n)/ln(n)).

2) At the point where the numbers become large enough to be "interesting" (i.e., numbers that cannot merely be put into a 64-bit integer, but can be arbitrarily large), your approach will face an interesting problem: the operation of looking up the nth item will grow because on most current hardware today, you might face trouble with memory management for all of your primes.  You can probably still be okay all primes that could be fit into a 32 bit integer, and hence discover the factors of all integers less than 64 bites, but beyond that, your approach will face clear trouble.  In any case, once you exceed 64 bits and start looking for factors of arbitrarily large integers such as a Java BigInteger, even if you could manage the memory, the performance analysis will need to be updated to account for the size of the actual integers you are considering.  Nikolay's analysis is good assuming that every division has uniform cost.  But if you start working with larger number representations, the assumption of uniform cost is broken.